# Windows cannot be installed to this disk. iscsi drive install

Tags: windows-7, windows, iscsi

I am trying to install a windows operating system on a remote iscsi drive

following this tutorial http://www.etherboot.org/wiki/sanboot/win2k8_iscsi_install

I get far as the drive selection screen in windows setup.

Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.
[image]

I don't have any motherboard with that can change it's controller mode.